# React embedding external js library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to embed 'timelines-chart' library to my React project.

After installing the library:

```
npm install timelines-chart
```

I added it to the project like this:

```
import TimelinesChart from 'timelines-chart/dist/timelines-chart'
```

The render() function looks like:

```
let canvas = <div></div>
const myChart = TimelinesChart().data(myData)(canvas);
```

and i got the error:

> TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
> (anonymous function)
> node_modules/timelines-chart/dist/timelines-chart.js:3658
> 3655 |
> 3656 | function attrConstant(name, value) {
> 3657 |   return function () {
> 3658 |     this.setAttribute(name, value);
> | ^  3659 |   };
> 3660 | }
> 3661 |

How should I use this library?

Answer (score 2):

As one of the answers mentioned, timelines-chart is not aware of React elements. Essentially, `<div></div>` is transformed to `React.createElement('div', {});`, which in turn returns an object. While it is possible to query your `div` with ID selector, the idiomatic way to access the underlying DOM node is via a `ref`. Also, since you want to preserve the `TimelinesChart` instance, it is probably a good idea to store its instance in a ref too. So your example would look like this:

```js
export function App() {
  const elemRef = useRef();
  const chart = useRef(TimelinesChart());

  useEffect(() => {
    chart.current.data(getRandomData())(elemRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={elemRef}></div>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
       </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Refs are useful for all kinds of things. You can view them as fields in a JavaScript class since, as I mentioned, the identity of the ref is preserved between different renders. So, in your example, every time React calls the function of your component (`App`), a new canvas TimelinesChart instance is created, while with refs it is the exact same object every time.

Answer (score 0):

Created working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-antonelli-wkhph

So the problem is that timelines-chart is just a regular JS library, it's not built for react, it cannot work with react components.
When you write

```
let canvas = <div></div>
```

canvas will not have reference to actual DOM div element, `div` in this case is React object.
But what this library expects is actual DOM element.

So one of possible solutions would be to actually render some div using react, and then on `componentDidMount` or using `useEffect` with empty array for second argument, you could query that element using `document.querySelector` and then pass it down to `TimelinesChart` like here:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var chartEl = document.querySelector("#chart");
    const myChart = TimelinesChart();
    myChart.data(getRandomData())(chartEl);
  }, []);
```

And full working component would be like:

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
   var chartEl = document.querySelector("#chart");
   const myChart = TimelinesChart();
   myChart.data(getRandomData())(chartEl);
}, []);
return (
  <>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
     </div>
  </>
);}
```